# Creating and mapping a CSS to a Crystal Report with the Java Plugin for Eclipse

Tags: java, css, crystal-reports

Hi i want to use a css file to load 3rd Party fonts without installing them. But when i set the Css Name nothing happens.

I'm using "cr4e-all-in-one-win_2.0.23" with "com.businessobjects.crystalreports.crsdk.libs_12.2.224.r3370"

I followed this procedure:

To create a CSS and map classes to a Crystal Report

Locate the Crystal ViewerReport default.css file.

Copy the file to the same directory and rename it.

If necessary, use a text editor to add or modify CSS classes.

Open the .RPT file of the Crystal Report to which you want to map the CSS classes.

Add or select a text object and open the Format Editor. In the CSS Class Name field, enter the CSS Class Name, type the class to which you want to map the text object.

Save the report.

Open the Reporting Services application and publish the report.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: firaGO;
  src: url(FiraGO-Light.ttf);
}

* {
  font-family: firaGO;
  color: blue;
}
```